# Error arranque Linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Instale Linux Mont 19 y 18.3 y todo venía muy bien en ambos casos, instale programas, apague y prendía la PC hasta que al iniciar antes del login la pantalla queda negra. Esto sucedió en ambas instalaciones.

Mí Notebook es una Dell inspiró 15 5000 gaming. Con GeForce GTX. Luego de cada instalación siempre cambie en drivers mánager a los drivers de la Nvidia.

[image]

Comment: Pareciera que fallo al cargar los parámetros del kernel. Al igual que [a esta persona](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected), deberias probar [cambiando los parametros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter). y agregarle al final: pci=nomsi ctrl x (para guardar) y luego reinciar.